# How to find the max number of times a sequence of characters repeats consecutively in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm working on a cs50/pset6/dna project. I'm struggling with finding a way to analyze a sequence of strings, and gather the maximum number of times a certain sequence of characters repeats consecutively. Here is an example:

String: `JOKHCNHBVDBVDBVDJHGSBVDBVD`

Sequence of characters I should look for: `BVD`

Result: My function should be able to return `3`, because in one point the characters `BVD` repeat three times consecutively, and even though it repeats again two times, I should look for the time that it repeats the most number of times.

Comment: Should we consider overlapping? For e.g.: If given sequence is 'ABA' and search space is 'ABABA', what's the answer?

Comment: Hey! The answer should be 1 still. Great observation!

Comment: @Axe319, I don't think so because the substring has to be consecutive...

Comment: Oh nevermind. I missed that requirement.

Comment: You haven't posted any code for us to help with.

Comment: @KennyOstrom It's because I have no idea how to start this... I've only thought of ways that definetly wouldn't work...

Comment: Write your own code that reads through the input once and brute forces it O(n). If that still has problems, you can make a good SO question fixing the overlapping issue.

Comment: Kenny, Kenny. I don't know how to brute force it... I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit lame, but one "brute-force"ish way would be to just check for the presence of the longest substring possible. As soon as a substring is found, break out of the loop:

EDIT - Using a function might be more straight forward:

```
def get_longest_repeating_pattern(string, pattern):
    if not pattern:
        return ""
    for i in range(len(string)//len(pattern), 0, -1):
        current_pattern = pattern * i
        if current_pattern in string:
            return current_pattern
    return ""

string = "JOKHCNHBVDBVDBVDJHGSBVDBVD"
pattern = "BVD"


longest_repeating_pattern = get_longest_repeating_pattern(string, pattern)
print(len(longest_repeating_pattern))
```

EDIT - explanation:

First, just a simple for-loop that starts at a larger number and goes down to a smaller number. For example, we start at 5 and go down to 0 (but not including 0), with a step size of -1:

```
>>> for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(i)

    
5
4
3
2
1
>>>
```

if `string = "JOKHCNHBVDBVDBVDJHGSBVDBVD"`, then `len(string)` would be `26`, if `pattern = "BVD"`, then `len(pattern)` is `3`.

Back to my original code:

```
for i in range(len(string)//len(pattern), 0, -1):
```

Plugging in the numbers:

```
for i in range(26//3, 0, -1):
```

`26//3` is an integer division which yields `8`, so this becomes:

```
for i in range(8, 0, -1):
```

So, it's a for-loop that goes from `8` to `1` (remember, it doesn't go down to `0`). `i` takes on the new value for each iteration, first `8` , then `7`, etc.

In Python, you can "multiply" strings, like so:

```
>>> pattern = "BVD"
>>> pattern * 1
'BVD'
>>> pattern * 2
'BVDBVD'
>>> pattern * 3
'BVDBVDBVD'
>>>
```

Comment: Hey @Paul M. Could you please explain what your code does? I don't understand this syntax: `for i in range(len(string)//len(pattern), 1, -1):
    if pattern * i in string:`

Comment: Thanks for the edit @PaulM. I'll take a look at it!

Comment: @NicolasF I've edited my post, and fixed two issues.

Comment: Hey @PaulM. I think there is only one issue. The `else` statement is not correct...

Comment: @NicolasF that `else` statement is executed only if your `for` loop completes without `break` ing.

Comment: ahhhh! Really? I edited then for nothing the answer...

Comment: @NicolasF I've edited my post to use a function instead, because it's more reusable. It also avoids using the special `for-else` syntax, which many people don't seem to know about. For the function, I've elected to return the actual longest substring found, rather than its length, but you could do it either way. This should also work for the case where `pattern` is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly less bruteforcey solution:

```
string = 'JOKHCNHBVDBVDBVDJHGSBVDBVD'
key = 'BVD'

len_k = len(key)
max_l = 0
passes = 0
curr_len=0

for i in range(len(string) - len_k + 1): # split the string into substrings of same len as key
    if passes > 0: # If key was found in previous sequences, pass ()this way, if key is 'BVD', we will ignore 'VD.' and 'D..'
        passes-=1
        continue
    s = string[i:i+len_k]
    if s == key:
        curr_len+=1
        if curr_len > max_l:
            max_l=curr_len
        passes = len(key)-1
        if prev_s == key:
            if curr_len > max_l:
                max_l=curr_len
    else:
        curr_len=0
    prev_s = s
    
print(max_l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that very easily, elegantly and efficiently using a regex.

We look for all sequences of at least one repetition of your search string. Then, we just need to take the maximum length of these sequences, and divide by the length of the search string.

The regex we use is `'(:?<your_sequence>)+'`: at least one repetition (the `+`) of the group `(<your_sequence>)`. The `:?` is just here to make the group non capturing, so that `findall` returns the whole match, and not just the group.

In case there is no match, we use the `default` parameter of the `max` function to return 0.

The code is very short, then:

```
import re

def max_consecutive_repetitions(search, data):
    search_re = re.compile('(?:' + search + ')+')
    return max((len(seq) for seq in search_re.findall(data)), default=0) // len(search)
```

Sample run:

```
print(max_consecutive_repetitions("BVD", "JOKHCNHBVDBVDBVDJHGSBVDBVD"))
# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my contribution, I'm not a professional but it worked for me (sorry for bad English)

```
    results = {}
# Loops through all the STRs
for i in range(1, len(reader.fieldnames)):
    STR = reader.fieldnames[i]
    j = 0
    s=0
    pre_s = 0
    # Loops through all the characters in sequence.txt
    while j < (len(sequence) - len(STR)):
        # checks if the character we are currently looping is the same than the first STR character
        if STR[0] == sequence[j]:
            # while the sub-string since j to j - STR lenght is the same than STR, I called this a streak
            while sequence[j:(j + len(STR))] == STR:
                # j skips to the end of sub-string
                j += len(STR)
                # streaks counter
                s += 1
            # if s > 0 means that that the whole STR and sequence coincided at least once
            if s > 0:
                # save the largest streak as pre_s
                if s > pre_s:
                    pre_s = s
                # restarts the streak counter to continue exploring the sequence
                s=0
        j += 1
    # assigns pre_s value to a dictionary with the current STR as key
    results[STR] = pre_s
print(results)
```